# jQuery Themeroller Gallery for Mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, themeroller

Is there a gallery of existing premade themes ready for download for jQuery Mobile just as they are for [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)? I did look around [jQuery Mobile Themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php) but couldn't find it (I know you can drag&drop the colors from Adobe kuler swatches but I'm not keen on that too much).

Comment: There are three premade themes listed on the [JQM site](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/#Themes), I don't know if there is anywhere with a larger collection

Comment: @Jack: thx for your comment, I didn't know about these three themes. Well, as it seems I'm left with fitting the colors together myself. I will leave the question open though for possible update in the future of some more extensive collection.

Comment: Today I just noticed http://driftyco.github.com/graphite/ which is not as themeroller for jQuery UI but it looks quite nice actually, and worth checking out.

Comment: Graphite does look pretty slick, but unfortunately, it's stuck on jQM 1.3.1.  There's an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/driftyco/graphite/issues/11) requesting upgrade.

Comment: @MaffooClock: Did you maybe find any new ones that may have emerged since this question is over 1 year old. Seems quite unbelievable no one would make something similar...

Comment: @Nikola: No, I did not.  In fact, it was my searching that brought me here :).  I decided to fart with the [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/) and have come up with a nice result!

Comment: @MaffooClock: great, I'm glad! Now we just find a way to publish these and boom - we have a repos ;)

Comment: Just for the record, there is already a theme roller for jquery mobile at https://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

Comment: @e.lopez: sure there is, as I stated in my question. What I'm searching for is the Gallery of existing premade themes, as jQuery UI has.

Comment: Oh, apologies... I totally mixed up things :-)

Comment: No problem, it happens ;). It's strange however, that even after all this time something hasn't come up.